# subtraction from size_t results in large positive number

Tags: c++, size-t

I just run into a nasty bug where I have a loop

```
for (auto i = 0; i < vec.size() -1; ++i) {
  //
}
```

with vec being an **emtpy** `std::vector`, thus vec.size() -1 evaluates to `2^64` on my system.

What's the correct way of writing the above loop?

Comment: why don't you just iterate over the vector itself using range based for loop? `for (const auto& el : vec) { do_something(el);}`

Comment: I'm just curious, why are you iterating over all the elements except the last one?

Comment: @ Borgleader one of those annoying "remove trailing whitespace situations" when concatenating strings

Comment: @user695652 Oh I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned type hence the problem, just do that this way:

```
for (auto i = 0U; i + 1 < vec.size(); ++i)
```

`0U` added to make `i` unsigned (to avoid warning), but I would better use `size_t` istead of `auto` in this case

Answer (score 0):

> What's the correct way of writing the above loop?

Keep the loop as it is, but add an `if`-condition that branches into the loop only if the vector isn't empty.