# runtime error: applying non-zero offset 18446744073709551615 to null pointer (basic_string.h)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, data-structures, number-theory

I am solving a question on leetcode where I have to multiply strings and I got this error which I cant understand

Line 518: Char 69: runtime error: applying non-zero offset 18446744073709551615 to null pointer (basic_string.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:527:69

Here is my code

```
string multiply(string s1, string s2) {
         vector<int> vec(s1.length()+s2.length(),0);
       for(int i=s2.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
           for(int j=s1.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
               int pro = (s1[j]-'0')*(s2[i]-'0') ;
               //borrow sent to next
               int sum = vec[i+j+1] + pro;
                vec[i+j+1] = (sum%10);
                vec[i+j] += (sum/10);
           }
       }
       string ans="";
       for(int i=0; i<(s1.length()+s2.length());i++){
           if(ans=="" && vec[i]==0){
               continue;
           }
           ans.push_back(vec[i]+'0');
       }
       if(ans==""){
           return 0;
       }
       return ans;

    }
```

LINK : https://leetcode.com/problems/multiply-strings/

Comment: Note that `s1.length() - 1` [doesn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893776/subtraction-from-size-t-results-in-large-positive-number) what you think it does. What is going to happen if `s1.length() == 0`?

Comment: actually according to question it is gaurented that length of string will be at least 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where **`ans=""`**,

 Instead of returning **`"0"`** (**string**), you are returning **`0`** (**Integer**).

As the return type is a string it is causing a problem.

```
if(ans=="")
{
   return "0";
}
```

This Should work fine, I think.

Answer (score 3):

```
       if(ans==""){
           return 0;
       }
```

is bad. This function is returning string, so `return 0;` means `return string(0);`.

Assuming `string` here is [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), the constructor

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

will be used for this.

This means to request to convert `nullptr` (converted from `0`) to a string, but this is invalid.

You should use

```
       if(ans==""){
           return "0";
       }
```

instead.